# Distance between root of $f$ and its Gaussian convolution

Tags: integration, gaussian, convolution

Let $f$ be a :

1. $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$,
2. for all $x> 0,~f(x)>0$,
3. for all $x< 0,~f(x)<0$,

I am struggling to find a bound for the distance between the root of $f$ and the root of its Gaussian convolution. Formaly,

> Let $f$ satisfies the previous properties and define $g$ as:
> $$g_\sigma(x):=\int_\mathbb{R}f(s)e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{2\sigma^2}}ds.$$
> From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745372/zero-crossing-for-convolution/4745403?noredirect=1#comment10066982_4745403), we know that $g_\sigma$ has a unique 0, denoted ${\lambda_\sigma}$. How can we bound the convolution's zero $\lambda_\sigma$ depending on $\sigma$ and the derivatives of $f$ ?

Numericaly, I think that $\lambda_\sigma$ is linear in $\sigma$. But I have no clue to for the derivatives...

Any hint, ideas or solution will be highly appreciated ! Thank you very much !

Since $\lambda_\sigma$ is a function of $f$ and $\sigma$, I have thought the implicit function theorem but I don't know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: What is $x^*_\sigma$? Is it $\lambda_\sigma$? Also, how come "linear in $\sigma$"? If e.g. $f(x)=e^x-1$, then $\lambda_\sigma=-\sigma^2/2$.

Comment: Thank you @IosifPinelis, I had edited my post and it didn't make any sense. Now I corrected it. I am looking for the difference between the zero of a function, and the zero of its gaussian convolution.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, Thank you for your example, is there a more general formula depending on $f$ and $\sigma$ ?

Comment: I think it can be shown that under minimal suitable conditions on $f$ we have $\lambda_\sigma\sim-\dfrac{f''(0)}{2f'(0)}\,\sigma^2$ as $\sigma\downarrow0$. If this is enough for you, I can try to write it up.

Comment: Thank you @IosifPinelis, it will be perfect !

Comment: This is now done.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$After some simple rewriting, we see that $\la_\si$ is the root $x=x_\si$ of the equation $G(\si,x)=0$, where
\begin{equation*}
    G(\si,x):=Ef(x+\si Z)[=\si\sqrt{2\pi}\,g_\si(x)\text{ if }\si>0]  
\end{equation*}
and $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.
To ensure that $G(\si,x)$ or, equivalently, $g_\si(x)$ is finite for all real $x$ and all small enough $\si>0$, assume that
\begin{equation*}
    |f(x)|\le Ce^{Cx^2/2}
\end{equation*}
for some real $C>0$ and all real $x$. We will also require that $f$ does not vanish at $\pm\infty$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    f_a:=\inf\{|f(x)|\colon|x|\ge a\}>0 
\end{equation*}
for each real $a>0$ and
\begin{equation*}
    |f'(x)|+|f''(x)|\le Ce^{Cx^2/2}
\end{equation*}
for the same real $C>0$ and all real $x$.

In view of your conditions on $f$, for each real $a>0$ and all real $x\ge a$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    G(\si,x)&\ge Ef(x+\si Z)1(Z>0)+Ef(x+\si Z)1(Z<-x/\si) \\ 
    &\ge f_a/2-CEe^{Cx^2+C\si^2Z^2}1(Z<-x/\si)\to f_a/2>0  
\end{aligned}
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
uniformly in real $x\ge a$ as $\si\downarrow0$. Similarly, for each real $a>0$ and all small enough $\si>0$ we have $G(\si,x)<0$ for all real $x\le-a$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    x_\si\to0\quad\text{as } \si\downarrow0. 
\end{equation*}

Let $G_1(\si,x)$ and $G_2(\si,x)$ denote, respectively, the first and second partial derivatives of $G(\si,x)$ w.r.t. $\si$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    G_1(0,x)=EZf'(x)=0 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \text{$G_2(\si,x)=EZ^2f''(x+\si Z)\to f''(x)$ as $x\to0$ and $\si\downarrow0$.}
\end{equation*}
So, by Taylor's expansion, for some $c_\si$ between $0$ and $x_\si$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    0=G(\si,x_\si)&=G(0,x_\si)+G_1(0,x_\si)\si+G_2(c_\si,x_\si)\si^2/2 \\ 
    &=f(x_\si)+0\,\si+(f''(0)+o(1))\si^2/2 \\ 
    &=(f'(0)+o(1))x_\si+0\,\si+(f''(0)+o(1))\si^2/2 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
as $\si\downarrow0$.

Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    x_\si=-\frac{f''(0)+o(1)}{2f'(0)}\,\si^2
\end{equation*}
as $\si\downarrow0$, provided that $f'(0)\ne0$.

---

**Details on \eqref{10}:** For each real $a>0$, $\si\in(0,\min(a,(4C)^{-1/2}))$, and real $x\ge a$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    G(\si,x)&=Ef(x+\si Z)1(x+\si Z>0)+Ef(x+\si Z)1(x+\si Z<0) \\ 
    &\ge Ef(x+\si Z)1(Z>0)+Ef(x+\si Z)1(Z<-x/\si) \\ 
    &\ge Ef(x)1(Z>0)-CEe^{C(x+\si Z)^2/2}1(Z<-x/\si) \\ 
    &\ge f(x)P(Z>0)-CEe^{Cx^2+C\si^2Z^2}1(Z<-x/\si) \\ 
    &\ge f_a/2-Ce^{Cx^2}\int_{-\infty}^{-x/\si}e^{(C\si^2-1/2)z^2}\,dz \\ 
    &\ge f_a/2-Ce^{Cx^2}\int_{-\infty}^{-x/\si}e^{-z^2/4}\,dz \\ 
    &\ge f_a/2-C\sqrt2\,e^{Cx^2}e^{-(x/\si)^2/4} \\ 
    &\ge f_a/2-C\sqrt2\,e^{(C-1/(4\si^2))a^2} \underset{\si\downarrow0}\longrightarrow f_a/2>0.  
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. Could you tell me how do you have the inequalities (the two) on $G(\sigma, x)$ please ?

Comment: @Gaetano : I have added further details on that.

Comment: Thank you for these very clear details!

Comment: By readiing your proof again, I was wondering why is the condition $f''(0)\neq 0$ is necessary ? Can we say in all the cases, $x_\sigma = O(\sigma^2)$ ?Thank you!

Comment: @Gaetano : To write $a\sim b$ (meaning $a/b\to1$), one needs $b\ne0$. Anyhow, now I have rewritten the result in a slightly more general form, not requiring the condition $f''(0)\ne0$.

Comment: Iosif Pinelis Thank you, I was wondering how to prove that $x_\sigma$is monotone on $(0,+\infty)$  (I didn't manage to exetnd your proof to answer that question) . Do you think that I should write another post (since it is slighlty different) ?

Comment: *Monotone in $\sigma$.

Comment: @Gaetano : I think that the question on the monotonicity is very different from the current one and requires different methods. So, I suggest you consider another post on that.

Comment: Thank you @Iosif Pinelis, I posted a more general question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453292/inequality-involving-convolution-roots) with a small bounty if you want to have a look.

Comment: Iosif, do you think that it is hard to show that $|x_\sigma|\leq K\sigma^2$ for all $\sigma>0$ ? I cannot find a way to generalize the reasonning in 0 you did in your answer...

Comment: @Gaetano : I think that, indeed, some other ideas would be needed for that purpose.

Comment: Iosif, after thinking about what could be added to prove an inequality on $|x_\sigma|$, I found out that one might use the implicit function theorem. Since $x_\sigma$ is defined as the zero of $G(x,\sigma)$, we then have $\frac{\partial_\sigma x_\sigma }{\partial \sigma}= \sigma \frac{G_2(x_\sigma,\sigma)}{G_1(x_\sigma,\sigma)}$ (after a change of variable in an integral). To bound the derivative, we have to find a lower bound of the denominator. ($G_1$ and $G_2$ denote the gaussian convolution of $f'$ and $f''$). Dou you think it might help ?

Comment: By the way, this formula confirms your asymptotic approximation :)

Comment: @Gaetano : The implicit function theorem is only local. The problem is that, here and elsewhere, you want inequalities to hold for all $\sigma>0$.

Comment: Iosif, last question: how to deal with $f'(0)=0$ ? My feeling is that this singularity is "artificial". If we consider $f(x) = x^3$, the zero $x_\sigma$ does not go to infinity... Thank you very much for all the help you provided me in this post !

Comment: @Gaetano : I think the exponent of $\sigma$ in the asymptotic as $\sigma\to0$ will depend on the smallest $k$ such that $f^{(k)}(0)\ne0$.