# Bound for zero-crossings of heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, heat-equation, zeroes

I am considering the following problem.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ the classical heat-diffusion problem:

$$\mathcal{P} : \left(\partial_t u (t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}^2u(t,x)\text{ with }u(0,\cdot) = f(x)\right).$$

Suppose that the initial condition $f$ satisfies the conditions:

1. $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ (smooth and bounded)
2. $f$ is negative before $0$ and positive after (one zero-crossings).

We know that the function $u(t,\cdot)$ has a unique zero-crossing point denoted $x_t$ (I can add details on that).

**My problem is the following: can one find a constant $K>0$ such that:**

$$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}_+,~|x_t| \leq Kt \text{ ? }.$$

As well done by @Iosif Pinellis in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452276/distance-between-root-of-f-and-its-gaussian-convolution/452305?noredirect=1#comment1174694_452305), we have an asymptotic approximation of $x_t$ as $t$ tends to 0.

Does anyone have an idea on that ?

Thank you very much!

*P.S.: feel free to make any remarks on MO guidelines*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$$\def\aha{{1/2}}$$\def\maha{{-1/2}}$
**Edit**. Now it looks correct.

I can prove that $x_t$ grows at most like $t$ for $t\geq 1$, up to a multiplicative constant.

For simplicity, assume that $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq 1$. Call
$$ 0<\varepsilon:=\min_{x\in[1,2]} f(x). $$
Now write $u$ as a convolution with the heat kernel (I will use the kernel for the equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ and drop the factor $1/2$, as this amounts simply to a linear rescaling of the time variable).
$$ u(t,x)=\int_\R f(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy=\int_\R f(t^\aha z)\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-\frac{(t^\maha x-y)^2}{4}}dz. $$
Call $\Phi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{4\pi}e^{-z^2/4}dz.$

We split the above integral in two pieces and we estimate both from below:
$$ u(t,x)\geq -\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-\frac{(t^\maha x-y)^2}{4}} dz + \varepsilon\int_{t^\maha}^{2t^\maha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-\frac{(t^\maha x-y)^2}{4}} dz=$$
$$ = -\Phi(-t^\maha x) + \varepsilon\left(\Phi(t^\maha(2-x))-\Phi(t^\maha(1-x))\right). $$
Now we use the estimate on $\Phi$ (which can be checked by differentiating both sides)
$$ \Phi(z)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{4}{|z|+1}e^{-z^2/4},\quad\forall z\leq 0 $$
and Lagrange formula to show that for $x\geq 0$ and some $g\in[1,2]$ we have
$$ u(t,x)\geq \varepsilon\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-g)^2}{4t}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{4}{|x/\sqrt t|+1}e^{-x^2/4t}\geq $$
$$ \geq \varepsilon\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-1)^2}{4t}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{4}{|x/\sqrt t|+1}e^{-x^2/4t}= $$
$$ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\left(e^{\log(\varepsilon) +\frac{x}{2t}-\frac{1}{4t}}-e^{\log(4)-\log(\frac{x}{t}+\frac{1}{\sqrt t}) }\right).$$
Simplifying, one obtains that for non-negative $x$, $u(t,x)$ is positive whenever
$$ \frac{x}{t}>h\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt t}+\frac{1}{4t}-\log(\varepsilon/4)\right)-t^\maha,$$
where $h=g^{-1}$ is the inverse of the function $g(z)=\log(z)+z/2$.
After further estimates on $h$, one can show that $u(t,x)>0$ whenever $t\geq 1$ and
$$ x>Ct$$
for some constant $C$ depending on $\varepsilon$ ($C=-\log(\varepsilon/20)$ should work). By symmetry, a similar bound holds from below, which implies that
$$ |x_t|\leq Ct $$
for all $t\geq 1$.
Combined with the asymptotic formula for small $t$, this should give the desired result.

I am not entirely sure every step of the proof is correct, but in any case this idea should work to establish the bound you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lorenzo Pompili for your detailed answer! I have two questions:
(i) : Could you provide details on how you get the very first inequality ? 
(ii) : Do you have an idea for getting a bound on $t\in[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Sure. For the first inequality, I use that $f(x)\geq -1$ for negative $x$ (because of the assumption on the $L^\infty$ norm), that $f(x)\geq\varepsilon$ on $[1,2]$, and $f(x)\geq 0$ on the remaining intervals. Concerning the second question, for the bound on $t\in[0,1]$ it is enough to show that $\partial_u(t,x_t)>0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ (you start from $u(t,x_t)=0$, differentiate w.r.t. $t$, and obtain $\frac{d}{dt}x_t=\frac{u_{xx}(t,x_t)}{u_x(t,x_t)}$). It should follow by similar methods, but I don’t immediately see how. My bounds are too loose for small $t$

Comment: I guess for small $t$ you really need to use that $f$ approaches $0$ smoothly as $x\to 0$, so instead of bounding $f(x)$ with $-1$ for negative $x$, it would be better to use $f(x)\geq x\cdot(1+\sup_{y\in[-1,0]} |f’(y)|)$, $x\leq 0$. Doing the same proof with this bound for $x\leq0$ would probably work.

Comment: * that $\partial_u$ should be $\partial_xu$

Comment: Thank you vrry much for all these details !

Comment: Last question: where do you need in your proof that $t\leq 1 $ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149126/discussion-between-lorenzo-pompili-and-gaetano).

Comment: is it ok for you if I show you what I've done so far (following your advice) and show you where I am stuck (in another answer to this post) ?

Comment: I forgot to mention your pseudo @Lorenzo Pompili, sorry

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo Pompili, I posted my attempt [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456861/proving-that-a-quantity-is-positive-gaussian-density-and-gaussian-cfd) I you want to have a look!